# How to make a div popout in the middle of the screen and making the rest of the site dark

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just say that in the new vimeo and want to know how this is accomplished

This is the the button

```
    <a href="/messages/compose?recipient=1667821" class="message btn" 
data-lightbox="">Send Message</a>
```

There is no onclick() , they get the href value and inserted into the div without refreshing the page..

Comment: it's another episode of ["It's a Modal Window"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window)

Comment: They load popup with link information using "message btn" class instead of onclick.

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan: onclick has to be in there somehow, even if it's not specifically defined in the HTML.

Comment: Yes but click event defined by js script internally like jquery done via .click event.

Comment: Let say they use .click() event but how they get the id of the user

Answer (score 2):

Without looking at their code, they probably bind a click handler later in their Javascript, possibly using jQuery. It would look like this:

**jQuery:**

```
$(".message").click(function() {
    // do the lightbox
});
```

**Vanilla Javascript:**

```
document.getElementByClass("message").onclick = function() {
    // do the lightbox
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/).

***[Click here to view their modal dialog demo / with source code](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal)***.

Comment: and the OP did not tag jQuery

Comment: @Joseph - They didn't say much.  Just offering a solution. =D